# Return observable before emitting event

Tags: javascript, observable

I created a function that if it does not have the object in memory, it fetches it before returning.

However when it has it in memory it was emitting instantly before allowing the subscribers to subscribe to the event.

To solve this i added  a setTimeout as in the example below, but i feel that it is *hacky*.

Question is, is there a better way (best practices) to solve this ?

```
itemSubject = new Subject<T[]>();
getAll(): Observable<T[]> {

    if (this.snapshot) {
        setTimeout(() => { //this is what i am trying to replace.
            this.itemSubject.next(this.snapshot)
        }, 0);
    }
    else {
        this.load().subscribe(
            (res) => {
                this.snapshot = (<any>res).data
                this.itemSubject.next(this.snapshot);
            }
        );
    }
    return this.itemSubject.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: what if the load function also emits value instantaneously, before the subscriber subscribes?

Comment: Hey @AshishDuklan, if you want it to always pass back the last emitted value on subscription you can use a BehaviourSubject, see more here: 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject
you can also use shareReplay to transform any observable into a behaviour subject, more info here: 
https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using Rxjs `of`.
To know more about it visit: [LearnRxJS.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of)

```
itemSubject = new Subject<T[]>();
getAll(): Observable<T[]> {

if (this.snapshot) {
    return of(this.snapshot); // requires rxjs library
    //setTimeout(() => {
    //    this.itemSubject.next(this.snapshot)
    //}, 0);
}
else {
    this.load().subscribe(
        (res) => {
            this.snapshot = (<any>res).data
            this.itemSubject.next(this.snapshot);
        }
    );
}
return this.itemSubject.asObservable();
}
```